# Usage of 'will' and 'would'

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Would someone tell me whether to use 'will' or 'would' in the following?

> 1. However, I realized eventually that those personal issues **would** not define my future but my academic performance **would**.
> 2. However, I realized eventually that those personal issues **will** not define my future but my academic performance **will**.

I am writing a Statement of Purpose, and want to mention the reason for poor GPA in one particular semester and how I overcame that.

Comment: for a poor GPA, realized, past tense, would, also past tense of will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find a huge confusion among native English speakers over the choice between **will** and **would**.

As a guide, it's best to use **would** after a main verb in the past tense. Thus:

> > He says he **will** go tomorrow

and

> He said he **would** go tomorrow

or, depending on the time frame

> He said he **would** go the following day.

In your example, after **realised** prefer **would**.

At the same time you need to be aware that **would** is frequently used in conditional sentences to talk about hypothetical situations, such as:

> I **would** travel if I had the money.

which makes it clear that the speaker doesn't have the money and implies that he doesn't expect to. To say:

> I **will** travel if I have the money

indicates intention and possibility. The speaker here is at least hopeful of travelling.

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/will-or-would

https://writingexplained.org/will-vs-would-difference

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/when-should-i-use-would-would-have-will-and-will-have